# Tangent Question: Find the Y-int?

Tags: calculus

Let $C$ be defined by $y=f(x)$.Suppose there's a tangent at $(4, 3)$. The tangent equation is $y=2x+5$. Let C be the curve

$$ y=\frac{x\cdot f(x)}{1+x^2}$$

Find the y-int of tangent to $C$ at the point with $x$-condition that $x = 4$

For this question what I did was just use y=mx+b, make it y=(2)(4)+5 which equals 13. So would that be the answer?

Comment: Is the tangent equation the equation of the tangent at 4 or is it the equation for the slope at any given x?

Comment: it's the equation of the tangent at 4

Comment: So $1/x + x  - 1 = 0$? That's a number (I think) not a function...

Comment: surely the point has to be $(4,13)$ the tangent does not go through $(4,3)$

Comment: Maybe the equation should be $y=2x-5$ that would work too.

Answer (score 1):

If the equation of the tangent is y=2x+5, then it's already in slope - intercept form, that is y=mx+b where b is the y-intercept. So the y - intercept of the tangent at 4 is 5.